# Debug web browser windows phone from pc

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8, browser, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug a web from a device with windows phone, from the pc. With Android, i just need to go to chrome://inspect and there i can see which device is connected, and it let me inspect the webs thar are opened in the device.

In the other hand, when I have tryed this with windows phone, it doesn't work. I have search for solutions, for example try to use weinre (https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/1.x/1.5.0/), start the server with weinre and connect my device to the computer.

In the documentation, it says i have to add this to the web page, and it will become my "debug target"

```
<script src="http://a.b.c:8081/target/target-script-min.js"></script>
```

But i don't have access to the source code, so i can't do that. And now i'm stuck again.
Do you know then how to debug and web, in windows phone? How to open the debug console and see it on my pc ? (the same functionally that chrome://inspect do with android?). Oh! the windows phone version is 8.1

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems odd that you're trying to debug something you cannot fix (i.e. you don't have access to change the source)?

Answer (score 1):

First you need Visual Studio. Open it up without loading any solution. And go to Debug -> Other Debug targets -> Debug Windows Phone Internet Explorer.

Enter your URL and you are good to go.

But it is important that the Visual Studio instance is empty (no solution loaded)